# Write igraph clustering to file

Tags: r, igraph

I am currently testing various community detection algorithms in the `igraph` package to compare against my implementation.

I am able to run the algorithms on different graphs but I was wondering if there was a way for me to write the clustering to a file, where all nodes in one community are written to one line and so on. I am able to obtain the membership of each node using `membership(communities_object)` and write that to a file using `dput()` but I don't know how to write it the way I want.

This is the first time I am working with R as well.  I apologize if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not have to do much with igraph, the clustering is given by a simple numeric vector. See `?write`.

```
write(membership(communities_object), file="myfile", ncolumns=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

`write(communities_object$membership, file="myfile", ncolumns=1)` also work